# Is it possible to have Next.js APIs under / rather than /api?

Tags: xcode, rest, next.js

I have a basic `GET` request API on my `Next.js` app. Something like

`http://localhost:3000/api/apple-app-site-association`

I know that's where Next.js puts all the APIs, but is there a way to have the API without the `/api` in between?

I want it to be like this `http://localhost:3000/apple-app-site-association`

Comment: Wouldn't that conflict with the pages routing though?

Comment: I think so, my workaround was putting the `apple-app-site-association` file (json with no extension) inside `/public` instead of serving it inside `/api` and setting a source inside `next.config.js`

Comment: If its a typical get request to serving a static file we can do something like here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10648